# Programmatically Switch Windows User Accounts using Java?

Tags: java, windows

I have an application written in Java that needs to run under another windows user account each time. My question is - is it possible to automatically create and switch windows user accounts using Java? For example, suppose I create two local user accounts - one called "test12" and one called "test123" and I'm logged in to "test123" - I need to be able to switch to "test12" and then back to "test123" (or a different account) purely using Java. Is this possible? How?

I understand there are several question on SO that address this issue however I've only seen the question in C# or .net not in Java (For example, the following question [Is it possible to Switch User Accounts programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281796/is-it-possible-to-switch-user-accounts-programmatically) was asked in C# and the question [Create Windows User programmatically c# .net (using PricinpalUser / CreateProfile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008742/create-windows-user-programmatically-c-sharp-net-using-pricinpaluser-createp) was asked in c#)

I am using windows 8 however I wanted the application to be able to run on Windows server 12 as well (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

You should try executing native commands :

snippet for doing so :

```
try {
// Execute a command without arguments
String command = "dir";
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

// Execute a command with an argument
command = "dir";
child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
   } catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Windows command for running under specific user (might not answer your question but can help you):

```
Navigate to C:\WINDOWS\system32

Enter the following command: runas /user:*computer name\*account name explorer.exe
```

source :

[Changing windows user in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183438/changing-windows-user-in-java)

http://lifehacker.com/290435/switch-user-accounts-from-the-command-prompt